# How to specify default Ubuntu 16.04 installation language in isolinux/lang?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, preseed, kickstart, custom-installer

I previously used this command to set english as the default language for my unattended Ubuntu installation in 14.04 and it worked perfectly:

```
echo en >> isolinux/lang
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 this doesn't work anymore. I have tried it multiple times with different permissions. I still see language selection window during unattended install.

Does anyone know how it should be done in 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a different workaround for this. Set Ubuntu installer to select default values automatically and proceed with installation:

```
sed -i -r 's/timeout\s+[0-9]+/timeout 1/g' /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
```

Source: https://github.com/fries/prepare-ubuntu-unattended-install-iso/blob/master/make.sh

Comment: Could you clarify the context where this command is run?

Comment: Inside extracted ISO files directory. If you have your ISO files extracted in `/tmp/iso`, then you would do `cd /tmp/iso` and execute the command above

Comment: Where did you set the default values in Ubuntu installer? You mean changing something in ubiquity or...? It makes sense to remove the timeout if the default language can be set for ubiquity-dm. I guess your use case of unattended install differs from mine of offering the install image user the correct language without interaction, so maybe you weren't solving the same problem originally anyway.
(sorry for mistakenly earlier posting this as an answer instead of comment)

Comment: @TimoJyrinki I didn't set default values, actually default language (English) was the one that I needed. I just needed to find a way to automatically select it. So that's what it does.