# How to skip the language selection screen and install menu on an autoinstall ISO 20.04

Tags: system-installation, cloud-init

Update: I found the solution in the accepted answer of this post: [How to specify default Ubuntu 16.04 installation language in isolinux/lang?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803425/how-to-specify-default-ubuntu-16-04-installation-language-in-isolinux-lang)

I'm trying to make an auto install ISO using this repo as a base: https://github.com/onedr0p/k8s-cluster-ubuntu-autoinstall.

Base Ubuntu ISO is: `ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso`

It works nearly flawlessly.

The issue is that when I insert the ISO and boot, it first asks for a language in a purple full screen page and then it goes to a menu that has an option to start the installation.

This is the step that I want to skip, I want it to select English and start the installation.

The next steps work without issue, it installs everything automatically.

The screens that I want to skip look like these:

[image]
[image]

Note that there is also this screen, but this one is fine, my cloud-config chooses the correct language automatically on that screen:

[image]

How could I achieve this? Is this something that I can set in the cloud-config? I'm thinking not, because it seems to load it only after you click "Install Ubuntu". Do I have to change something in the ISO? (The code that makes the ISO is in the file `docker-entrypoint.sh` in the repo that I linked above.)

There are so many ways to do automatic installs and some of them are outdated, I can't find anything useful on Google.

I also noticed that, if I reboot the computer instead of choosing a language, it will start the installation automatically...

Here's the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   quiet  ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server (safe graphics)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   quiet  nomodeset ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
grub_platform
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
    exit
}
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
    fwsetup
}
fi
```

and the `/isolinux/txt.cfg`:

```
default live
label live
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append   initrd=/casper/initrd quiet  ---
label live-nomodeset
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server (safe graphics)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append   initrd=/casper/initrd quiet  nomodeset ---
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

I can see that this is where the menu comes from, I'll try some stuff like setting `set timeout=5` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Try/Install screen

Have a look at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

The command `maybe-ubiquity` will send you to the **Try/Install** screen.

The command `only-ubiquity` will send you to the **Install** screen.

If you remove these, you should go directly to **Try** Ubuntu.

If you are booting using Syslinux, edit `/isolinux/txt.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find those commands, I edited my post with the content of those files, I'll try playing with them and see what I can figure out.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice it was server. I am downloading server now.

Comment: Have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231796/remove-ubuntu-20-04-try-install-screen/1231801#1231801

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work either, I updated my post with a link to another post that solved my problem